# How to prevent stopping updating errorlog file in editor

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, editor

I'm using VSC for PHP-programming. For debugging I watch the error log file from PHP in a editor like a source file while the PHP-app is running.
Normaly when the program is running all the text send to the error log file appears in the editor. But after a while, the text disappear. To see te content of the file again, I have to close the editor window (tab only) and reopen the file. If the PHP-app is still appending text, the text appears as normal at the end. But sortly, the content disappears again and the editor stays open empty. There is no change in the content of the file caused by reopening the file.
I have it on the server and with SSH-connection.

I found a work arround by using 'Get-Content  PHP-error.log -Wait' - in Powershell. But still it interupts with a error : The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

Is this a bug? Or is there a fix?

Comment: I never had a try to open the error log from Visual Studio Code. In the meanwhile, you could open a SSH window and just run `tail -f /var/log/your-error.log` and it will display all changes during execution.

Comment: Tail doesn't work on a Windows-server.

Comment: As you mentioned the SSH connection I thought that you where running your PHP on a Linux remote server. If the SSH daemon is running on a Windows server, such as over Cygwin, you might could have tail or another alternative. If it’s possible, you could also install XDebug and just enable it for a while in order to debug remotely without printing to your error log.

Comment: The erro log is used as report file. So XDebug is not a solution. 
VSC on server gives the same problem. The SSH-connection is not the cause.

Comment: It was a issue. In the January 2022 (version 1.64) releasenote 138850: Opened editor can end up empty after a file change on disk. 
Problem is solved now.